# Alphanumeric Sort Datagrid - Reusable Worry Free Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

Friends,

I have about 20-30 datagrids that have different data on all of them.  Is there a way that I can sort a datagrid with out writing custom code in each sorting event?

I want some code that all i need to do is pass it in a name of a datagrid, and perhaps a direction.

I don't want to make a call back to the database, but instead, i have a List  Each Datagrid will have a different Generics List Value.

Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use [LinqDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.aspx) on all  of them and paging and sorting will be taken care of for you without writing a single line of code.

Comment: Okay, but how can I add a LinqDataSource if I populate it from code?